# Laravel Get Updated_at gives wrong Return

Tags: php, sql, laravel, mariadb

I want to return the `updated_at` field from my database when making a GET Request.
I always get back something like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "updated_at": {
                "date": "2015-03-08 12:52:28.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "updated_at": {
                "date": "2015-03-19 13:40:39.000000",
                "timezone_type": 3,
                "timezone": "UTC"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But I actually want that `updated_at` to look like this:

```
..."updated_at":"2015-03-08 12:52:28"...
```

I am using a Transformer to return the data like this:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Project;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class ProjectDateTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Project $project)
    {
        return [
            'id'         => (int) $project->id,
            'updated_at' => $project->updated_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?
I am using MariaDB as the database encase this has something to with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel turns `updated_at`/`created_at`/`deleted_at` timestamps into [Carbon objects](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon). You can use Carbon's various formatting options to get the particular format you want, or you can use `(string)$project->updated_at` to cast it as a string, which will use the default format (which matches what you want).

Comment: Is it possible to change the format to a unix timestamp?

Comment: @Sebi55 You can turn it into all sorts of things. http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-getters For timestamp, it's as simple as `$project->updated_at->timestamp`.

Comment: I meant when I post something